# freeglut fails to open display with valgrind

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, valgrind, glut

I'm running the Eclipse IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 with the Valgrind plugin. I've been working on a game in C++ for quite some time, and I seem to have a memory error somewhere. Normally, I trace these with Valgrind. However, glut fails to initialize when I run valgrind. I should note that the game initializes without a problem when I'm not using valgrind. The code for my main function is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char windowTitle[12] = "Game Window";
  printf("Initializing Glut...\n");
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  printf("Glut initialized!\n");
  alutInit(&argc, argv);
  Game_Object* game = new Game_Object(windowTitle, 1200, 675, argc, argv);
  delete game;
  printf("game ended\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The resulting output to the console is:

```
Initializing Glut
freeglut (/home/dsnettleton/Documents/Programming/Eclipse/workspace/Plutoids/Debug/Plutoids): failed to open display ''
```

Obviously, the program isn't getting very far with valgrind running.
It's really disheartening to be in such a final stage of my development, only to get stuck trying to weed out a memory error. What might be keeping glut from initializing, and what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Not a real answer to your problem, but: Did you try using a garbage collector, like Boehm_CG for memory debugging. Mozilla uses it for exactly this purpose. http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/leak.html

Comment: I tried it, but it's not giving me any additional output to the console. I don't think the problem is a leak per se; it's probably related to invalid pointers, or possibly double-freeing some memory somewhere (Every once in a while when I end the program, it'll crash with a corrupted double-linked list message).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my guess: your IDE is probably missing the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. Somewhere you have to configure the environment to set `$DISPLAY` before launching Valgrind.

Launch a terminal and `echo $DISPLAY`. Its value is probably `:0.0`.

In the worst case, I'd try using `setenv()` inside the C code or set DISPLAY in the command line that launches Valgrind (none of these cases was tested, they may not work).

Comment: That was it. I had to add the argument `-DISPLAY=:0.0` to valgrind. Thank you so much; I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Also you have to add this environment variable DISPLAY:=0.0 inside Eclipse.
In the launch configuration of your executable, add a Display variable to the Environment tab, or select to inherit environment.

> Run->RunConfiguration...->Environment

Now click on

> New

and add

> DISPLAY :0

in it

Comment: Smart. Thanks.
Add new variable with these features:
Variable : DISPLAY:0 
VALUE: {leave empty}